# Pandas - how to use a dataframe index to search for values

Tags: pandas

Pandas 1.0.5

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
        ['Joe', 30, 60],
        ['Bill', 40, 70],
        ['Tim', 50, 80],
        ] 

d = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'age', 'salary'])
d = d.set_index('name')
d.loc['Bill'].count()
```

> 2

```
d.loc['Steve']
```

> KeyError: 'Steve'

Is there a way I can get 0 or False instead of dying with "KeyError"?

In a SQL database, when I search for a value that does not exist, the database does not die with error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to count the number of occurrences.

```
d.index.isin(['Bill']).sum()
d.index.isin(['Steve']).sum()
```